# Gitlab CI Kubernetes Agent Self Signed Certificate

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubectl, gitlab-ci-runner, bitnami

I have following .gitlab-ci.yml config:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - echo "Hello, Rules!"
    - kubectl config get-contexts
    - kubectl config use-context OurGroup/our-repo:agent-0
    - kubectl get pods
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true    
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "develop"'
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true    
  tags: 
    - docker
```

This fails on following error:

Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

We are running a self-hosted gitlab instance with a self-signed certificate. The issue is bitnami/kubectl:latest being a non root docker container, and it is described here in the official gitlab docu to be used:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_workflow.html#update-your-gitlab-ciyml-file-to-run-kubectl-commands

I have tried the "echo "$CA_CERTIFICATE" > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-ca.crt && update-ca-certificates" for injecting a certificate, but that fails due to not having privileges and SUDO not existing in this container.

`kubectl get certificates` fails on not being able to connect to localhost:8080

Any pointers on how to get a self-signed certificate to work with connection with kubectl and agent authentication, or what is perhaps considered a secure way of making this work?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have just hit the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully Gitlab provides a way to provided a path to a `ca-crt-file` via flag during start up of the agent.

Broadly the process for loading a self-signed certificate is:

1. create a file containing the public key of your self signed certificate, ensuring to concatenate any other public keys involved in the signing chain
2. if you can do the above it's possible to apply this file as a K8S ConfigMap, if not (you include the private key) then create it as a K8S Secret as the proceeding documentation indicates.
3. modify the K8S Deployment to mount the ConfigMap/Secret to the agent container then add a new line to the container `args` to point to the file - `--ca-cert-file=/certs/ca.crt`

[GitLab Kubernetes Agent: provide custom certificates to the Agent Issue #280518 (thank you Philipp Hahn)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/280518#note_844351782)

> In the kind: Deployment deployment section add the following things:
>
> - In spec:template:spec:containers:args append `- --ca-cert-file=/certs/${YOUR_CA}.crt` - expand ${YOUR_CA} here manually
> - In `spec:template:spec:contaiers:volumeMounts` add a new block:

```yaml
- name: custom-certs
  readOnly: true
  mountPath: /certs
```

> - In `spec:template:spec:volumes` add a new block:

```yaml
- name: custom-certs
  secret:
    secretName: ca
```

Official Docs:

[Providing a custom certificate for accessing GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html#providing-a-custom-certificate-for-accessing-gitlab)

> You can provide a Kubernetes Secret to the GitLab Runner Helm Chart, which will be used to populate the container’s /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/certs directory.
> Each key name in the Secret will be used as a filename in the directory, with the file content being the value associated with the key:
>
> - The key/file name used should be in the format <gitlab.hostname>.crt, for example gitlab.your-domain.com.crt.
> - Any intermediate certificates need to be concatenated to your server certificate in the same file.
> - The hostname used should be the one the certificate is registered for.

[Gitlab Agent Helm Chart Deployment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-agent/-/blob/25cdd3771e1132c542fa61c1e17d6c8dff934cc0/templates/deployment.yaml#L49)

```yaml
- --ca-cert-file=/etc/agentk/config/ca.crt
```